# Errors with trying to install express on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, express

When I give command `npm install express` it throws following errors (on windows32bit using cmd)

```
C:\Aditya\Study and Work Stuff\nodeprojects\contactlistapp>npm install express
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "express"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! enoent getaddrinfo ENOENT registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! enoent getaddrinfo ENOENT registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Aditya\Study and Work Stuff\nodeprojects\contactlistapp\npm-debug.log

C:\Aditya\Study and Work Stuff\nodeprojects\contactlistapp>
```

Comment: Do you have a proxy on your network?

Comment: No, not using proxy server

Comment: Which version of node and npm do you use?

Comment: Node-v6.10.3-x86, node.js 32 bit